# List the rooms which have no activities scheduled in them on a day 1

Tags: sql

I have a `tblActivity` table which has `RoomID`, and `Day`.

I need to list `RoomID` which is never set with `Day` 1.

```
RoomID Day  
XXX123 1
XXX124 3
XXX123 2
XXX125 5
```

For example; `RoomID XXX123` got activity on `Day` 1 and also at another row `Day` 2. So I will not list that `RoomID`. I need to list only the ones which never have activity on `Day` 1.

Is it possible?

Comment: Yes, it should be possible.

Comment: What is your expected output..?\

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try the following:

```
Select RoomID From tblActivity 
Where RoomId Not IN (Select RoomId From tblActivity Where Day = 1)
```

> The above query will select all the RoomIDs which are never set with
>   Day 1..Hope, this solved your problem!!

Comment: Wuuw It's Working

Comment: I'm glad its working. You can upvote and accept my answer. Thanks!!

Comment: I wrote the same query and I was the first one to answer this. You should have accepted my answer. There needs to be some fair play.

Comment: your query was wrong and corrected it after seeing my answer.. check your edit history

Answer (score 0):

```
select room_id
from table_name
where room_id not in 
(select room_id from table_name where day = 'day_1');
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Edited !. Changed activity_id to room_id. Confused on columns names

Answer (score 0):

Just for fun , a different approach

```
Select a.Roomid from tblActivity a
left join
(select roomid 
from tblActivity 
where day=1
) b
on a.roomid=b.roomid
where b.roomid is null
```